# Programatically check if object parameter is default(object.GetType()) in C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing an `ObjectHasValueConverter : IValueConverter` for WPF.

The relevant function is `Convert(object value, ...)`.  I want essentially want to do

```
return value != default(value.GetType())
```

Unfortunately, it seems `default` is a compile-time keyword and `IValueConverter` doesn't have a generic equivalent, so I can't just do `default(T)`.

Obviously if value is an instance of a class or an array I can just check for null.

```
if (value.GetType().IsValueType | value.GetType().IsArray)
{
    return value != null;
}
```

I have a special case for `string`s, returning `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value)`.  For structs and other primitives, I'm hoping there's something cleaner than

```
if (value is int | value is short | value is long | ...)
{
    return (int)value != 0;
}

if (value is float | value is double)
{
    return (double)value != 0;
}

if (value is bool)
{
    return !(bool)value;
}
...
```

I've scoured SO before writing this, but all the answers I found had to do with reflection and getting the members of a value type.  I didn't find anything relating to types that are put on the stack.

Comment: Your second snippet will fail really hard...